# Why is * .tlb not visible?

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-9.3, vba, visual-studio, classextensions

I've created a Visual Studio 08 Active X - MXCommands dll for a VBA button within ArcMap 9.3.1.  I'm able to load and use the .tlb on my computer; however when I try it on my test computer the .tlb file is not visible.  The MXCommand is not listed in the Component Category Manager under ESRI MXCommands on the test computer.  I used RegAsm (e.g. C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\RegAsm.exe C:\Temp\Mydll.dll) to try and register it on the test computer, but this did not help.  Both computers are running MS XP professional.  Any suggestions of what I could do or try next would be greatly appreciated.

I also tried this command to register it:

```
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\RegAsm.exe C:\Temp\Mydll.dll/tlb: Mytlb.tlb/codebase
```

And received a RegAsm Error  - RA0000 The given path's format is not supported.

Comment: I would be surprised if RegAsm accepted mixed back and forward slashes as delimiters in filenames.  If the forward slashes indicate switches, they likely need to be preceded by whitespace.  This might explain the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your command line should read:

`C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\RegAsm.exe C:\Temp\Mydll.dll /tlb:Mytlb.tlb /codebase`

Not directly related to your problem, but I would also advise against naming the type library file differently than the DLL as it violates the standard naming convention. I.e. use `Mydll.tlb` instead of `Mytlb.tlb`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition, the reason I was not seeing the .tlb file extension was because the windows folder option, "Hide extensions for known file types" was checked.  After un- checking it, I could then see the .tlb extension in the Open dialog.